# Does possibility to specify enabled protocols for web-application in IIS exist in MSBuild?

Tags: iis, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

I create webdirectory in IIS, using MSBuild task:

```
<WebDirectoryCreate
   VirtualDirectoryName="$(VirtualDirectoryName)"
   VirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath="$(VirtualDirectoryPath)"
   AccessExecute="true"/>
```

Now I look for possibility to specify enabled protocols (http, https, net.tcp) for this webdirectory using MSBuild. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had no luck to find any custom MSBuild task to handle above described action.  Anyway I can still use appcmd.exe in order to do that:

<Exec Command='%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app "Default Web Site/WebAppName" /enabledProtocols:http,net.pipe,net.tcp'></Exec>

In fact I can't even find case now where person running my msbuild task has no appcmd.exe installed :)    hm... ok... whatever...

Answer (score 1):

A minor correction to the answer, your site name must be followed by a slash:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app "MySite/" /enabledProtocols:http,net.pipe,net.tcp
```